# can‘t resolve the @param annotation in java program

Tags: java

How can I fix it in Idea.Thx.

my code：

```
  /**
 * MultipartFile 是springmvc提供的文件上传的接受的类
 * 底层会调用HttpServletRequest request 中的request.getInputStream()融合;
 * @param multipartFile
 * @param dir
 * @return
 */

public class UploadServiceImp {

public Integer uploadImg(MultipartFile multipartFile, String dir) {
    //指定文件上传的目录
    File targetFile = new File("F://temp/" + dir);
    try {
        multipartFile.transferTo(targetFile);
        return Code.SAVE_OK;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Code.SAVE_ERR;
    }
}
}
```

problem description：

Cannot resolve symbol 'multipartFile'

Cannot resolve symbol 'dir'

these are two images url.[status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwX8X.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJymu.png)

Comment: Class doesn't have parameters. Methods or constructors do so you need to move that JavaDoc before your `uploadImg` *method*, not before *class* `UploadServiceImp`.

Comment: no screenshots of plain text, please

Comment: @Pshemo I get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move comment after sign of class and before sign of function
Your class (raw sign) don't have any params, so they can't be resolved
But function's params are 'invisible' for comments outside class.
See https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html for more help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a typo? You are using '*multipartiFile*' instead of '*multipartFile*'.

Comment: I have found the mistake and fixed it, what you said is one of the causes. The other reason is "@param" should be resolved at the methods not class